# C++ edit code from within code?

Tags: c++, windows, com

I have a simple AI program I have made and I want to add the command "add command" which would actually chance the source code from the executed program. Is there anyway to do this? I was thinking I would have pre-built strings with the blocks of code I have for commands such as:

```
else if (input == "what are you?" || input == "What are you?")
            {
                cout << "I am a multi-purpose, artificial intelligence program designed to help simplify life." << endl;
                ISpVoice * pVoice = NULL;

                if (FAILED(::CoInitialize(NULL)))
                    return FALSE;

                HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    hr = pVoice->Speak(L"I am a multi-purpose, artificial intelligence program designed to help simplify life.", 0, NULL);
                }
            }
```

And just make the command ask for input possibilities, and output.

Is this something that is doable or is this just my inner StarTrek fan taking over my practicallity?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code.  However, there are likely better ways to accomplish what you are after.

Comment: Maybe you can use pointers to function for that.

Comment: This is really not a practical way to write an AI or to develop an algorithm. It might be a fun learning exercise, but it clearly doesn't scale.

Comment: I know this isn't practical to begin with, it really is just for fun, but if possible I still think it'd be cool to get this command to work.

Comment: Modifying the memory at a function pointer address is just as likely to segfault or have no effect on the execution (depending on system arch and OS) as it is to actually do what you'd think...

Answer (score 1):

C++ is compiled, not interpreted.   So, you have basically no hope of changing the code after the compilation happens.

However, you can use callbacks / delegate patterns as well as passing pointers to functions and classes around...

Comment: What if I simply had the code output the new lines to a notepad file (or some equivalent) and I just hand enter the new lines and re-compile when I'm done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change your programs execution during run-time.  These are known as *hooks*.

For example, when an OS receives an event, it iterates through it's list of "hooks", notifying them of the event.

Some hooks can be appended while other hooks are daisy-chained.

Take a keyboard driver for example.  Let's assume there is a vector that is called when a keypress occurs. An installer saves the address in the vector and writes the address of the driver into the vector.  The installer then gives the original address from the vector to the driver.  This gives the driver first preference over keypress.  The driver then calls the address from from the vector with the keypress data (original data or modified data).  Some viruses also work this way.

The big, difficult issue, is creating new code on the fly.  If you want to generate new C++ code on the fly, you will have run the compiler to generate the code and figure out how to replace or connect it to your program.  Interpretive languages are much better suited for this.

Your project is not impossible, just a lot of work when using C++.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to alter the source code of your program as you'd like, and then when your program exits, start the compiler to rebuild your executable. This is a bit timing-sensitive as the build should not finish before your application has shut down entirely. using an `atexit` handler can help to ensure that you start the build late in the shutdown procedure.

In this way, you get a new program every time you run it, but the program does not change *while* running.